# android - substract edittext's text

Tags: java, android

Currently, I'm making a cashier app. I have an `EditText` which contains item(string) that is included in the shopping cart. I can add items by touching button. However now I just need a button to subtract the `EditText` by the latest inputted text to `EditText`.

For example, if I add milk(1$), sugar(0.8$), the`EditText` will show "milk + sugar". Then I want to remove the latest item that is sugar. So I touch delete button and I want now the `EditText` shows only milk. So it substracts "sugar" only. My brain no longer has any idea.

Note: `TextView` can replace `EditText` in this case.

And by the way, I can't show my code. I'm not bringing my laptop.

Last, if you have another way to remove not only the latest input, like I can delete the milk word even it's not the latest input,  that's good:).

Thank you for your attention!:)

Comment: Where are you storing the selected items?

Comment: I dont store them. I just tell user item they select. Then I store total price as int. So when user add item it adds price to total price. By the way, storing selected items gives me idea. Thank you!

Comment: See my idea below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the selected items in a `List`.

```
List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Update the `EditText` as follows,

```
private void updateEditText() {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++ ) {
        text.append(item);
        if(i != selectedItems.size() -1) {
            text.append(" + ");
        }
    }
    editText.setText(text.toString());
}
```

Method to add to selected `List`,

```
private void addItem(String item){
    // add some duplicate checking logic if needed

    // add the item to selected list
    selectedItems.add(item);

    // update the EditText
    updateEditText();
}
```

Method to remove item from selected `List`,

```
private void removeItem(String item){

    // remove the item from selected list
    selectedItems.remove(item);

    // update the EditText
    updateEditText();
}
```

For Example,

User selects "Milk" and "Sugar":

```
addItem("Milk");
addItem("Sugar");
```

User removes "Milk":

```
removeItem("Milk");
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wow it works! But it needs a change. That code will result the same item even I enter different item. So I change text.append(item) to text.append(selectedItems.get(i)). By the way, thank you! I'll send the code later:)